# Derby Apache - Connect exception when I try to connect on port 1527

Tags: java, database-connection, derby

I was trying to connect in order to create a db in Derby for a class project when I have encountered the following problem: I've downloaded the zip file from the official Derby website, currently I'm using the 10.12.1.1 version, I've executed the command startNetwork that shows me the log file who says that is ready to accept connections on port 1527, but when I try to connect with the command (in ij): connect `'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Mydb;create=true';` it shows me the error:
ERROR 08001: java.net.ConnectException: connection error to server localhost on port 1.527 with message Connection refused (I've translate it from italian, maybe something different in original language) what I don't understand is why it shows me the port 1.527 instead 1527, any idea?

Comment: I'm working on MacOS Sierra

Comment: I guess it's the thousand separator.

Comment: It sounds like your Derby Network Server actually isn't starting successfully. Look at the file 'derby.log' in the directory where you started the Network Server and see if there are any more clues there. Use the 'ps' command to see if the Java process for the Network Server is still running. Use 'netstat' to see if it is successfully listening on port 1527.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a "/" in your connection string: `1527/Mydb` this will cause the error i guess. if not have you tried to use the full file path?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but it keeps to show the same error, what do you mean with 'the full file path'? I'm making a request in order to create a db, I don't have a path for it

Comment: even for creating you have to specify a path where the db file should be stored. example from me:`jdbc:derby:G:\\test\\test\\Test\\Database`